# Re-arrange ArrayList from month Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

The JSONArray below should be re-arranged according to key "date_course". For example, For the year 2015,

January

### --- All january item

--

February

### --- All February item

--

March

### --- All March item

--

April

### --- All April item

--

..etc.

```
 [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "date_course": "2015-01-29",
            "nom": "Wow Urbain de St Pierre",
            "lieu": "St Pierre",
            "zone": "Nord",
            "distance": "15",
            "denivele": "5000m cumule",
            "lieu_depart": "St-Pierre",
            "lieu_arrivee": "Fin de chantier",
            "tarifs": "15",
            "dossards": "Ou recuperer les dossards",
            "challenge": "Challenge Decathlon",
            "parcours": "information",
            "image_parcours": "link to image",
            "organisateur_id": "1",
            "nom_organisateur": "Organisateur 1",
            "email_organisateur": "organisateur1@gmail.com",
            "telephone_organisateur": "1234343",
            "site_web_organisateur": "site.com",
            "site_inscription_organisateur": null,
            "course_qualificative": "0",
            "categorie_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "date_course": "2015-01-09",
            "nom": "Sentier de L'onf: La Providenc",
            "lieu": "Saint Denis",
            "zone": "Nord",
            "distance": "11",
            "denivele": "800m cumule",
            "lieu_depart": "Allee de la foret 97400 Saint Denis",
            "lieu_arrivee": "Saint Denis",
            "tarifs": "18",
            "dossards": "Ou recuperer les dossards",
            "challenge": "Challenge Wow",
            "parcours": "information",
            "image_parcours": "link to image",
            "organisateur_id": "2",
            "nom_organisateur": "Organisateur 2",
            "email_organisateur": "organisateur2@gmail.com",
            "telephone_organisateur": null,
            "site_web_organisateur": null,
            "site_inscription_organisateur": null,
            "course_qualificative": "1",
            "categorie_id": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "date_course": "2014-12-17",
            "nom": "Wow Urbain de St Paul",
            "lieu": "St Paul",
            "zone": "Est",
            "distance": "19",
            "denivele": "500m cumule",
            "lieu_depart": "St-Paul",
            "lieu_arrivee": "St-Paul",
            "tarifs": "10",
            "dossards": "Ou recuperer les dossards",
            "challenge": "Challenge City Sport",
            "parcours": "information",
            "image_parcours": "link to image",
            "organisateur_id": "2",
            "nom_organisateur": "Organisateur 3",
            "email_organisateur": "organisateur3@gmail.com",
            "telephone_organisateur": "35645654",
            "site_web_organisateur": "organisateur.com",
            "site_inscription_organisateur": "siteinscription.com",
            "course_qualificative": "0",
            "categorie_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "date_course": "2015-03-11",
            "nom": "Sentier de la Marie",
            "lieu": "St Gilles",
            "zone": "Ouest",
            "distance": "14",
            "denivele": "800m cumule",
            "lieu_depart": "Mairie de St Gilles",
            "lieu_arrivee": "Mairie de St Gilles",
            "tarifs": "18",
            "dossards": "Ou recuperer les dossards",
            "challenge": "Challenge Wow",
            "parcours": "information",
            "image_parcours": "link to image",
            "organisateur_id": "2",
            "nom_organisateur": "Organisateur 4",
            "email_organisateur": null,
            "telephone_organisateur": null,
            "site_web_organisateur": "organisateur4.com",
            "site_inscription_organisateur": "organisateur4.com",
            "course_qualificative": "0",
            "categorie_id": "1"
        }
    ]
```

I extracted the year and month for every date_course tag but now i am stuck in matching the dates and rearanging the arraylist. Here is my workings.

```
ArrayList<CourseCopy>filteredList = new ArrayList<CourseCopy>();

        Date date = null;
        if (myApp.getArrCalendarModelList()!=null){
            calItem = myApp.getArrCalendarModelList();
            for (int i=0;i<calItem.size();i++){
                String string = calItem.get(i).date_course;
                DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
                try {
                    date = format.parse(string);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                filteredList.add(new CourseCopy(date,calItem.get(i).nom,calItem.get(i).lieu,calItem.get(i).zone,calItem.get(i).distance,calItem.get(i).denivele,
                        calItem.get(i).lieu_depart,calItem.get(i).lieu_arrivee,calItem.get(i).tarifs,calItem.get(i).dossards,calItem.get(i).challenge,
                        calItem.get(i).parcours,calItem.get(i).image_parcours,calItem.get(i).organisateur_id,calItem.get(i).nom_organisateur,calItem.get(i).email_organisateur,
                        calItem.get(i).telephone_organisateur,calItem.get(i).site_web_organisateur,calItem.get(i).site_inscription_organisateur,calItem.get(i).course_qualificative,calItem.get(i).categorie_id));

            }

            Collections.sort(filteredList, new Comparator<CourseCopy>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(CourseCopy lhs, CourseCopy rhs) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return lhs.getDate_course().compareTo(rhs.getDate_course());
                }
            });
        }
```

Can someone give me a hint or help me to get the desired results please.

Comment: have you ever heard about dictionary containers? fx HashMap? ... `HashMap<int, HashMap<int, YourElementClass>` where firs `int` will be year, second `int` month in the year

Comment: Use Collections.sort for sort the data based on your requirement. You need to find how to implement it with date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just convert String date to Date object

```
for (int i=0;i<calItem.size();i++){
    String string = calItem.get(i).date_course;
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = format.parse(string);
    calItem.get(i).setDate(date);
}
```

store date in each Item in your calItem
after that you can sorting it just like this

```
Collections.sort(calItem, new Comparator<Item>() {
  public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
      return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
  }
});
```

update:

you can call it like this

```
if (myApp.getArrCalendarModelList()!=null){
    calItem = myApp.getArrCalendarModelList();
    for (int i=0;i<calItem.size();i++){
        String string = calItem.get(i).date_course;
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = format.parse(string);
        calItem.get(i).setDate(date);
    }
    Collections.sort(calItem, new Comparator<Item>() {
      public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
          return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry but can you give me an example

Comment: yes, but i didn't understand this point Collections.sort(calItem, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
  public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
      return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
  }
}); where should i place it and what is <MyObject> in your answer

Comment: my bad for that MyObject, you can call that after the loop in first block code

Comment: thanks in my Item model tag  "date_course" is of type "string" (public String date_course;) may this cause havoc ?

Comment: you need a Date type object to easily sort by Date, just convert that String to Date like my answer above.

Comment: Thank you i marked your answer as right answer but one last thing you can answer me if you want to, when a new item begins in a new month how can i add a header for this month only e.g. January then all january items then Header february add items for february etc

Comment: use a loop to check the month, if month != last_month then show new header

Comment: I have done this  http://pastie.org/private/1sqgdmfazpytbqo4dqyydq#10-11  but how can i can precedent month value.